# Hibernate primary key as foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to make a column referencing another entity an ID. I have `Currency` class and `AuditSystem` class. `Currency` has simple string ID and ID of `AuditSystem` should be an object of type `Currency`. I was playing around with @IdClass and made my classes implement Serializable but can't figure out how to make it work because I still get errors.
I believe it's a trivial problem but really can't come up with anything.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_system")
public class AuditSystem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Currency currency;
    private Float audit;
    private Timestamp created;
}
```

.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "currencies")
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String icon;
    private Timestamp created = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
}
```

How to properly map these entities?

Comment: Which relationship is between AuditSystem and Currency? Many to One?

Comment: @Mara one to one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My asumption is that you still need to have it's own @Id field in AuditSystem. And create relationship between those two entities. So something like this

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_system")
public class AuditSystem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String code;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Currency currency;

    private Float audit;
    private Timestamp created;
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "currencies")
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="currency")
    private AuditSystem auditSystem;

    private String name;
    private String icon;
    private Timestamp created = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
}
```

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn should help in case when primary key is also foreign key
[Hibernate doc @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association)

Comment: I've added @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "currency", referencedColumnName = "code") to the AuditSystem and now I get SerializationException from Hibernate.